# Draw a triangle in a graph with dynamic values in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

I want to draw a triangle with dynamic values with base down and sharp edge up. How can I do that?

Comment: what you need is a simple horizontal UIView drawn at three points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    //This set the line color
    [[UIColor blueColor] setStroke];

    [[UIColor redColor] setFill];
     UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    //Starting point
    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
    //Vertice one
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(1, 1)];
    //Vertice two
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 1)];

    [path closePath];

    //fill path with the defined color
    [path fill];
    //draw the stroke with the defined color
    [path stroke];

}
```